# iOS - resource content is accessible to public

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, cocoa-touch, uiwebview

In my iOS app, I have to load a static html file which has some sensitive information in a web view. So I have placed that file in the resource folder. I am using this code to load it in the web vie :

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"index" ofType:@"html" inDirectory:@"www"]];

[webview loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url]];
```

This work, but since this html contains sensitive information and we can see all the files in the resource folder on jailbroken devices, this seems like a big security issue.

- So is there any other place I can store this html files?
- Is there a way I can disable the resource folder access.

Answer (score 0):

Do not use `loadRequest` because it limits you to data presentable as URL (hence limited to certain file locations). `UIWebView` has other methods too: `loadHTMLString` and `loadData`. These allow you to load *arbitrary data*, which means it can be declared as code variable and compiled into your binary. If this is still not good enough for your "sensitive information", you can encrypt the data before compilation with a symmetric cipher, decrypt before loading and delete immediately after loading. The cipher key obviously needs to be a part of your binary. You can further obfuscate by making the actual cipher a temporary result of some predefined computation (like, most simply, a XOR of two other blocks stored in different places).

This all is just obfuscation. If your information is so sensitive that it will be worth the effort for someone to reverse engineer your code and/or do memory dumps, he will do it. You are trying to "protect" in the same way as the infamously impotent DRM.

Comment: One could authenticate with a server and then the server could send the key to the encrypted html file, the key would be stored in the Keychain.

Comment: If the poster has some server on his command, then *the file itself* can be sent _assymetricaly_ encrypted and none of the hacks would be needed. The technology exists, it's called SSL. The fact that poster doesn't want to use it means to me, that he doesn't have/want any server involved.